# Como usar Urls Amigáveis em pesquisa com método GET

Tags: php, get

Eu gostaria de tornar esse link:

`meusite.com/?searchInput=Eu+fui+viajar&categorySearch=Filme&submitSearch.x=19&submitSearch.y=17`

em

`meusite.com/category=Filme&search=Eu+fui+viajar`

.htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1

php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2500M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
php_value max_input_time 6000000
php_value memory_limit 2500M
```

Eu não sei muito sobre Urls Amigáveis, então não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer, dei uma olhada na internet, porem não achei nada parecido com oque eu quero.

Form:

```
   <form method="GET" class="floatLeft formSearch">
    <div class="formSearchDiv">
        <input type="search" name="searchInput" class="searchInput floatLeft">
        <select name="categorySearch" maxlength="255" class="categorySearch floatLeft">
                <option value="Todos" selected="selected">Todos</option>
                <option value="Serie">Serie</option>
                <option value="Filme">Filme</option>
                <option value="Anime">Anime</option>
                <option value="Filme Adulto">Filme Adulto</option>
                <option value="Desenho">Desenho</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
                <option value="Jogos">Jogos</option>
        </select>
        <input type="image" name="submitSearch" src="<?=DIR_IMAGES ?>lupa.png" class="submitSearch floatLeft">
    </div>
</form>
```

Get:

```
if(isset($_GET['searchInput']))
{   
    $pesquisa = $_GET['searchInput'];
    $categorySearch = $_GET['categorySearch'];
    //aqui chamo o metodo SQL para separar pela pesquisa e categoria
}
```

Comment: Lucas, bom dia.<br>
Mostre o restante do código do formulário por gentileza.

Comment: Lucas, bom dia.
Mostre o restante do código do formulário por gentileza.

Comment: @ThiagoSantos Já coloquei na pergunta

Comment: Não seria melhor uma url com barras verticais?                                     Tipo **meusite.com/category/filme/search/eu-fui-viajar**

Comment: @MaxRogério Mas como fazer isso automaticamente ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia O modelo [MVC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC) se encaixa certinho com seu projeto.

Comment: @LucasCarezia So você usar um framework mvc em php eu conheço  [CakePHP](https://cakephp.org/pt), [Zend](https://framework.zend.com/) e [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Tenho um projetinho que estou desenvolvendo a fins de conhecimento no qual o método de url amigável está da seguinte forma:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Pegando os valores da url

**arquivo.php**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['url']) && !empty($_GET['url'])){
     $url = array_filter(explode("/", $_GET['url']));
     print($url);
   }
 ?>
```

Pronto! Agora você tem um `array` com os valores que foram passados via url.
No seu caso, como você tem `meusite.com/category=Filme&search=Eu+fui+viajar`

Em vez de passar sua url assim...

Você passaria a url da seguinte forma: `meusite.com/category/Filme/search/Eu+fui+viajar`

e na saída (`print_r($url)`) da variável apareceria:

`Array ( [0] => category [1] => filmes [2] => search [3] => Eu fui viajar )`

Basta agora trabalhar com os valores que você obteve no array

Comment: Olá, eu não entendi muito bem como aplicar esse trecho de código, eu tentei colocar ele logo abaixo onde eu pego a busca(`if(isset($_GET['searchInput']))`), porem não resultou em nada.

Comment: Como disse, a variável `$url` iria virar um array, ai é só pegar os valores dentro do array, ex: `echo $pesquisa = $url[3];`, irá printar na tela `Eu fui viajar`, citando novamente `Basta agora trabalhar com os valores que você obteve no array`

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, tente fazer da seguinte forma:

form:

```
<form method="GET" class="floatLeft formSearch">
<div class="formSearchDiv">
    <input type="search" name="search" class="searchInput floatLeft">
    <select name="category" maxlength="255" class="categorySearch floatLeft">
            <option value="Todos" selected="selected">Todos</option>
            <option value="Serie">Serie</option>
            <option value="Filme">Filme</option>
            <option value="Anime">Anime</option>
            <option value="Filme Adulto">Filme Adulto</option>
            <option value="Desenho">Desenho</option>
            <option value="Software">Software</option>
            <option value="Jogos">Jogos</option>
    </select>
    <img src="<?php=DIR_IMAGES ?>lupa.png" />
</div>
```

Get:

```
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{   
$pesquisa = $_GET['search'];
$categorySearch = $_GET['category'];
}
```

Não irá ficar exatamente como você quer, mas será bem parecido!

Answer (score 0):

uma solução que fiz é criar um arquivo chamado busca.php que vai fazer isso

```
$termo = $_GET['termo'];
header("Location:".$url_site.'busca/'.$termo);
```

no .htacess fiz assim

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^busca/([-_a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=busca&termo=$2 [L]

/*esta segunda tem o parametro parte que é paginação*/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^busca/([-_a-z0-9]+)/parte-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=busca&termo=$2&pag=$3 [L]
```